# Prove that $\textrm{lip} L \leq \left(\sum_{j=1}^n || L(e_j) ||^2\right)^{1/2}$

Tags: linear-transformations, lipschitz-functions

Prove that $\textrm{lip} L \leq \left(\sum_{j=1}^n || L(e_j) ||^2\right)^{1/2}$ where $e_j = (\delta_{jk})_{1\leq k \leq n}$ is standar basis, $L$ is linear transformation $L: \mathbb{R}^n \to Y$, $Y$ is normed vector space and norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is defined as standard Euclidean norm.

What I have tired is following:  $\textrm{lip} L = \sup_{a\ne b} \frac{||L(a) - L(b)||}{||a-b||}$, then I tried writting vectors  $a$ and $b$ using basis vectors and then using linearity of $L$ have got something but not what I need. Can someone please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\|x\|_2$ denote the Euclidean norm of any $x\in \Bbb R^n,$ i.e.
$$\|x\|_2=\left(\sum_{j=1}^nx_j^2\right)^{1/2}.$$
Then,
$$\begin{align}\textrm{lip} L&= \sup_{\|x\|_2=1} \|L(x) \|
\\&\le\sup_{\|x\|_2=1}\sum_{j=1}^n|x_j|\|L(e_j)\|
\\&=\sup_{\|x\|_2=1}\sum_{j=1}^nx_j\|L(e_j)\|
\\&= \left(\sum_{j=1}^n\| L(e_j)\|^2\right)^{1/2},
\end{align}
$$
the last equality being the Cauchy-Schwarz theorem
$$\sup_{\|x\|_2=1}\sum_{j=1}^nx_jy_j=\|y\|_2$$
applied to
$y_j=\| L(e_j)\|.$

Comment: Note that "the last *equality*" could be replaced by $\le,$ i.e. Cauchy-Schwarz *inequality* $\sum_{j=1}^nx_jy_j\le\|x\|_2\|y\|_2$  is sufficient for our purpose.